# liblsoda: Using OpenMP with gcc to thread LSODA ODE solver in C

Tags: c, algorithm, openmp

I am trying to thread a reentrant algorithm using OpenMP with limited success. There is a C version of the FORTRAN LSODA routine available on github. It is used to solve first order ordinary differential equations. It has gone through several versions, but the most recent one is by Simon Frost and can be found here:

https://github.com/sdwfrost/liblsoda

The library comes with a simple test example that I updated to thread using OpenMP. There are several outstanding questions I have regarding a parallel implementation. My most "successful" attempt is below (the elapsed time for solving is not decreasing and the solutions sometimes vary):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "common.h"
#include "lsoda.h"
#include "omp.h"

#define BILLION 1000000000L

#define NUM_THREADS 2       // Number of threads for OpenMP

struct timespec start, end;
long long int timeValues[2];    
long long unsigned int deltaTimeArray;  
double msTime = 0.;

int fex(double t, double *y, double *ydot, void *data)
{
   ydot[0] = 1.0E4 * y[1] * y[2] - .04E0 * y[0];
   ydot[2] = 3.0E7 * y[1] * y[1];
   ydot[1] = -1.0 * (ydot[0] + ydot[2]);

   return(0);
}

int test(void)
{
   # ifdef _OPENMP
   printf("Compiled by an OpenMP-compliant implementation.\n");
   # endif

   // Begin timing the algorithm
   clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
   timeValues[0] = (BILLION*start.tv_sec) + start.tv_nsec;

   omp_set_dynamic(0);
   omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);

   int nThreads = 0;

   #pragma omp parallel
   {
      double  atol[3], rtol[3], t, tout, y[3];
      int     neq = 3;
      int     iout;

      y[0] = 1.0E0;
      y[1] = 0.0E0;
      y[2] = 0.0E0;

      t = 0.0E0;
      tout = 0.4E0;

      struct lsoda_opt_t opt = {0};
      opt.ixpr = 0;
      opt.rtol = rtol;
      opt.atol = atol;
      opt.itask = 1;

      rtol[0] = rtol[2] = 1.0E-4;
      rtol[1] = 1.0E-4;
      atol[0] = 1.0E-6;
      atol[1] = 1.0E-10;
      atol[2] = 1.0E-6;

      struct lsoda_context_t ctx = {
        .function = fex,
        .neq = neq,
        .data = NULL,
        .state = 1,
      };

      lsoda_prepare(&ctx, &opt);

      #pragma omp master
      nThreads = omp_get_num_threads();

      #pragma omp for
      for (iout = 1; iout <= 12; iout++)
      {
         lsoda(&ctx, y, &t, tout);

         printf(" at t= %12.4e y= %14.6e %14.6e %14.6e\n", t, y[0], y[1], y[2]);

         if (ctx.state <= 0) 
         {
            printf("error istate = %d\n", ctx.state);
            exit(0);
         }
/*
         if (iout == 1) tout = 4.0E-1 * 10.0E0;
         if (iout == 2) tout = 4.0E0 * 10.0E0;
         if (iout == 3) tout = 4.0E1 * 10.0E0;
         if (iout == 4) tout = 4.0E2 * 10.0E0;
         if (iout == 5) tout = 4.0E3 * 10.0E0;
         if (iout == 6) tout = 4.0E4 * 10.0E0;
         if (iout == 7) tout = 4.0E5 * 10.0E0;
         if (iout == 8) tout = 4.0E6 * 10.0E0;
         if (iout == 9) tout = 4.0E7 * 10.0E0;
         if (iout == 10) tout = 4.0E8 * 10.0E0;
         if (iout == 11) tout = 4.0E9 * 10.0E0;
         if (iout == 12) tout = 4.0E10 * 10.0E0;
*/
         tout = tout * 10.0E0;
      }

      lsoda_free(&ctx);
   }

   if  (nThreads == NUM_THREADS) 
   {
      printf("The expected number of threads, %d, were used.\n", NUM_THREADS);
   }
   else 
   {
      printf("Expected %d OpenMP threads, but %d were used.\n", NUM_THREADS, nThreads);
   }

   // End timing the algorithm
   clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
   timeValues[1] = (BILLION*end.tv_sec) + end.tv_nsec;

   deltaTimeArray = timeValues[1] - timeValues[0];
   timeValues[0] = timeValues[1];
   msTime = deltaTimeArray * pow(10, -6);

   const char *elapsed = "elapsed";

   printf("%13s\n%13.06lf\n", elapsed, msTime);

   return(0);
}

int main(void) 
{
   for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) 
   {
      test();
   }

   return(0);
}

/*
 The correct answer (up to certain precision):

 at t=   4.0000e-01 y=   9.851712e-01   3.386380e-05   1.479493e-02
 at t=   4.0000e+00 y=   9.055333e-01   2.240655e-05   9.444430e-02
 at t=   4.0000e+01 y=   7.158403e-01   9.186334e-06   2.841505e-01
 at t=   4.0000e+02 y=   4.505250e-01   3.222964e-06   5.494717e-01
 at t=   4.0000e+03 y=   1.831976e-01   8.941773e-07   8.168015e-01
 at t=   4.0000e+04 y=   3.898729e-02   1.621940e-07   9.610125e-01
 at t=   4.0000e+05 y=   4.936362e-03   1.984221e-08   9.950636e-01
 at t=   4.0000e+06 y=   5.161833e-04   2.065787e-09   9.994838e-01
 at t=   4.0000e+07 y=   5.179804e-05   2.072027e-10   9.999482e-01
 at t=   4.0000e+08 y=   5.283675e-06   2.113481e-11   9.999947e-01
 at t=   4.0000e+09 y=   4.658667e-07   1.863468e-12   9.999995e-01
 at t=   4.0000e+10 y=   1.431100e-08   5.724404e-14   1.000000e+00
*/
```

It seems there are several variants of "omp.h" and the version I used can be found here:

https://sites.uclouvain.be/SystInfo/usr/include/omp.h.html

I'm not sure how this algorithm is meant to be threaded. The first outstanding question is whether or not the for loop that calls the lsoda( ) routine should be threaded since tout has a loop dependency. If it was an increment (as is the case in my actual implementation) it could simply be added as a second increment statement in the for loop using the comma operator (Edit: apparently this cannot be done with OpenMP - for loops must be of canonical form and cannot have two increment expressions). This is the reason for the commented out portion of code that updates tout based on the value of iout. Even using that clunky block of code sometimes results in the wrong solution.

The provided test example was written with the test( ) function embedded in a for loop and called in main (over one iteration). I'm not certain of the logic behind this, but in my case I am doing something similar where the test( ) routine is called many times within a for loop in main. The problem with threading that for loop is again loop dependency, in which each successive solution (the y[ ] values) is dependent on the previous solution. I know that this algorithm is capable of being threaded, but I can't seem to successfully implement it. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> It seems there are several variants of "omp.h" and the version I used can be found here: [...]

No.  You are not at liberty to choose some random OMP header.  You should use the one provided by the OMP implementation you are using, else you risk undefined behavior.

> I'm not sure how this algorithm is meant to be threaded. The first
>   outstanding question is whether or not the for loop that calls the
>   lsoda( ) routine should be threaded since tout has a loop dependency.

You are right to be concerned about the dependency.  OpenMP has no magic for that -- the programmer is repsonsible for dealing with dependencies.  In this case, however, you have viable options for breaking the dependency involving `tout`, among them:

- precompute an array of `tout` values and pass elements of that array:

  ```
  double touts[12] = { 0.4 };

  for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++) touts[i] = 10 * touts[i - 1];

  // ...

  lsoda(&ctx, y, &t, touts[i - 1]);
  ```
- compute the appropriate `tout` at function call time:

  ```
  lsoda(&ctx, y, &t, tout * pow(10, i - 1));
  // ... and avoid modifying tout later in the loop ...
  ```

Watch out for other dependencies, however.  In particular, if `lsoda()` both reads and modifies the data pointed to by its other arguments, then that may introduce additional dependencies that are harder -- perhaps impossible -- to deal with.

You seem to be saying that that is indeed the case:

> The problem with threading that for loop is again loop dependency, in
>   which each successive solution (the y[ ] values) is dependent on the
>   previous solution.

If `lsoda()` computes and stores new values of the elements of `y`, and those depend in a difficult to predict way on the original values, then that's game over.  You are not going to break that dependency, and without breaking it, your *best* outcome is that you get correct output without any speedup.  Not that you can safely depend on seeing the best case.

> I know that this algorithm is capable of being threaded, but I can't seem to successfully implement it.

Not all algorithms are parallelizable.  It's plausible that you could use OpenMP and `lsoda()` to concurrently solve several *separate* problems, and it is conceivable that `lsoda()` could be parallelized internally (I have not evaluated that possibility), but I see no reason to think that your particular test case could be effectively parallelized.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. You were correct and this approach to threading the algorithm is not possible. I was however able to thread a loop in main that calls lsoda() for what amounts to be, as you said, "solving separate problems." While not necessarily ideal, it gets the job done successfully with a huge performance boost.